# How to capture still frame from video on iOS?

Tags: ios, photos, video

I have a video on my iPhone that I recorded using my iPhone. I want to extract a single frame as a still image, preserving the full quality and native resolution of the recording.

I know it's possible to take a screenshot of video, but I'm not sure if that ends up being a lower resolution image. Also, it just feels clumsy to use a screenshot because HD the time I end up with UI controls over top the image.

Is there a way, without third party software, to extract a full resolution still image frame from a video on iOS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I highly recommend a free app called [Frame Grabber](https://framegrabberapp.com). It captures still frames from a video, maintaining both original quality up to 4K and metadata (datetime, gps...). It's free and I find it brilliant.

Comment: I just tried this and it is perfect. Must-have app for iOS!

Comment: this is great although this also includes a third-party app.

Comment: It is perfectly made by a top German developer, good call.

Comment: Sadly, it is [under a new owner](https://arthurhammer.de/2023/06/frame-grabber-acquired/) and no longer free.

Comment: App allows about 3 free frame grabs (per some time period), then requires a $20 a year subscription.

Answer (score 6):

**No**, there is no option in the photos app to extract a single frame.

Depending on the video resolution you may or may not end up with a lower resolution screenshot. If your video resolution is higher than the screenshots' resolution, you end up with a lower resolution image in the end. Read more about [video resolution](https://docs.appmanager.io/docs/screenshot-sizes) on [iPhones](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/iphone-11-and-11-pro-12-tips-for-shooting-better-videos/) and [screenshot sizes](https://docs.appmanager.io/docs/screenshot-sizes).

The easiest way though would be to either use a third party app or - if you import the videos to a computer anyway - do it on a Mac/PC.

---

More about this: [different methods](https://www.iosappweekly.com/turn-video-into-picture-iphone-ipad/), [Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8363394)